# Cannot implicitily convert type `double[]` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<double>`

Tags: c#, syntax, for-loop, double

I am getting the following error message with the code below. I thought the data type `List<double>` was the same as `double[]` but that C# required it to be instantiated using the first syntax for the variable to work as an object. What am I doing wrong or is my thinking wrong?

```
Cannot implicitily convert type `double[]` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<double>`
```

Code:

```
private void RunScript(List<Curve> crv, double nb, ref object DivPts)
  {

    List<double> nbtemp = new List<double>();
    List<double> Divpt = new List<double>();

    for(int i = 0; i < crv.Count;i = i + 2)
    {
      nbtemp = crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true);
    }

    Divpt = nbtemp;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of having two `List<double>` variables that reference the same list object?

Comment: @cdhowie, I thought it would be clearer, is it not?

Comment: It's really not clearer.  It's confusing why you need two locals with the same type to refer to the same object.

Comment: A List<type> is a generic collection a double[] is an object array of a specific type `double` why are you mixing the two?  The two are not the same, not even close, one didn't even exist until .NET Framework 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a list is not an array, even though the concepts are somewhat similar. The `List<T>` class in C# is actually implemented with a behind-the-scenes array.

If you want to set a List from an array, you can use something like this:

```
nbtemp = new List<double>(crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true));
```

that will create a new List, and initialize it with the array. You can also use the `AddRange` method of the `List`, if you would like to append an array to an existing list, like this:

```
nbtemp.AddRange(crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an assignment and it is hard to tell what DivideByLength returns, if a single value then use:

```
nbtemp.Add(crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true));
```

Otherwise, if it is returning an array, try changing your definition to allow the list to contain arrays:

```
List<double[]> nbtemp = new List<double[]>();
```

Note that `List` is not equivalent to `double[]`. `List` has many features that a simple array does not. You can see the differences by looking at the two different MSDN articles for which methods are publicly exposed.

[List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx)

Also, your for loop as it stands is using an assignment. Without a change to that part of the code, you will only assign the last iteration of the for loop to the variable nbtemp (assuming you remove the error)

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert from Array to List, but you can easily call:

```
nbtemp = crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true).ToList();
```

Or, since you already have to Lists defined, you could also:

```
nbtemp.AddRange(crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true));
```

Comment: @JoelEtherton - Gotta love the race to the click. :-)

Answer (score 0):

They are both `IEnumerable` implementers but they are not equivalent types. You will need to perform a cast or a method call. In the code above I would say you'd need:

```
nbtemp = (crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true)).ToList();
```

or

```
nbtemp.AddRange(crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true).toArray()
```

Comment: There are a couple of very similar answers that offer more explanation, but also which answer the question as asked. The question explicitly requested conversion to a `List`, not an array. Further, your syntax for converting to an array is incorrect (it’s not `toArray`). I don’t see what value this adds to this thread.